# Is there in C++ a way to determine a variable type like "is_type_same_v(a, int*[3])" without adding the `decltype` keyword?

Tags: c++, c++17

I want to know whether there is a way in C++ to determine a variable type like `is_type_same_v(a, int*[3])` without adding the `decltype` keyword?

Such as,

```
int (*a)[3];
using namespace std;
cout<<is_same_v<decltype(a), int(*)[3]> <<endl;
// Is there sth like,
// cout<<is_type_same_v<a, int(*)[3]> <<endl;
```

I think the second way will be more straightforward.

Comment: Why would you want to avoid `decltype`?

Comment: you can write a function template that you can call like `is_same<int(*)[3]>(a)`, type will be deduced then. Whether this is really needed or more clear is opinion based, I think not. Also you will have to deal with array to pointer decay, which is much simpler with `decltype`

Comment: I think it looks more simpler, something like `isinstance` in Python.

Comment: thats a valid motivation, though consider that trying to mimic one language in another typically  leads to something that isnt idiomatic in either of them.

Comment: But C++ is not Python and experienced C++ programmers expect to see idiomatic code for idiomatic operations.

Comment: Ok so you worry about decltype, but you still use "C" style 2D arrays? like ` int(*)[3]` ? this would be a std::vector<std::array<int,3>> in C++ and `using namespace std;`  is ot recommmeded either.  Anyway delctype is just C++'s name, not simpler or harder then isinstance (just different). Type it a few times and you get used to it.

Comment: only after writing the answer I realized that `isinstance` is a whole different story. I dont know python by heart, but I expect that an instance of `struct foo : bar` is an instance of `foo` and also is an instance of `bar`. `std::is_same` on the other hand only compares two types, not more

Comment: If you want more readable code you can create type aliases.  `using my_data_t = std::vector<std::array<int,3>>;  my_data_t a; using instance_of_t = decltype(a); std::cout << std::is_same_v<my_data_t,using_instance_of_t> << "\n"`;

Comment: Anyway the core of your confusion is still trying to apply Python concepts to c++, just don't.

Comment: Do you want to compare the static compile-time type or the dynamic runtime type of derived classes used with a pointer to the base type? Or is this case not happening in your specific code?

Comment: I might not be able to express my original motivation very clearly, but I just want to write one less key word of `decltype`. By the way, I am sincerely thankful for your discussions, which inspire me a lot.

Answer (score 4):

You can write a function template that deduces the type of `a` like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>


template <typename T,typename U>
bool is_same(const U& t){
    return std::is_same_v<T,U>;
}

int main()
{
    int (*a)[3];
    std::cout<< is_same<int(*)[3]>(a);
}
```

Instead of `decltype` a function templates tempalte argument deduction can be used to deduce a variables type. Whether it is simpler, clearer, or more straightforward to write is up to opinions.

If you compare with pythons `isinstance` you need to consider that `isinstance` must take into account inheritance relation between types. `std::is_same` does not do that, it merely checks if two types are the same or not.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I found it did not work on type of `const int&`.